# How to dispose MediaCapture without playing shutter sound

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

How to disable camera shutter sound programmatically, it is always making sound when I take pictures, I am calling Dispose method of MediaCapture which makes that sound. Is there any way to disable that sound?

Below is the initialization code:

```
  private async Task InitializeQrCode(CaptureElement captureElement)
    {
        string error = null;
        try
        {
            if (mediaCapture == null)
            {
                mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                var _deviceInformation = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

                var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
                settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
                settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
                settings.AudioDeviceId = "";
                if (_deviceInformation != null)
                    settings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformation.Id;

                await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

                var maxResolution = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo).Aggregate((i1, i2) => (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
                await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);

                if (mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusChangedSupported)
                {
                    var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
                    focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange;
                    focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
                    focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
                    focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;

                    mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
                }

                await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.SetAutoAsync(true);

                mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
                mediaCapture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
            }

            captureElement.Source = mediaCapture;
            await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogBox.ShowOkMessage(this, "Error:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And here's the code for capturing image, on CapturePhotoToStreamAsync shutter sound is getting played:

```
 var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(imgProp, stream);


            stream.Seek(0);
            var wbm = new WriteableBitmap(WPAppConstants.Dimension.ImageEncodingWidth, WPAppConstants.Dimension.ImageEncodingHeight);
            await wbm.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            var result = bcReader.Decode(wbm);


            if (result != null)
            {
                var torch = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
                if (torch.Supported) torch.Enabled = false;
                await StopQrCodeScan();

                var resultEvent = Result;
                if (resultEvent != null)
                {
                    resultEvent(null, new CameraClickedEventArgs { EncodedData = result.Text });
                }
            }
```

Demo Project Onedrive [Link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C62D6F31C394F473!5626&authkey=!ALcLbCSsTmGwfrc&ithint=file%2Czip)

Comment: Calling Dispose on the MediaCapture will not trigger a shutter sound under normal conditions. You should post the smallest piece of code possible that is showing these symptoms, and we'll be able to help you a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

The question as you posed it is:

> How to dispose MediaCapture without playing shutter sound

The answer to that is to call (assuming you're running the preview, since you should pretty much always run it when you're capturing):

```
await mediaCapture.StopPreviewAsync();
captureElement.Source = null;
mediaCapture.Dispose();
```

Executing that code will not play a shutter sound. For reference, see the [UWP CameraStarterKit SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit), which will only play the shutter sound when a capture is started or stopped.

That being said, I noticed some contradictions in your question, where you said:

> it is always making sound when I take pictures, I am calling Dispose
>   method of MediaCapture which makes that sound

Implying that both the captures and the disposing are triggering a sound. You might be getting these concepts a little confused. The [Dispose method of the MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn278858) releases unmanaged resources. Calling Dispose will not trigger a shutter sound by itself and it has nothing to do with the shutter sound that you may hear when you take pictures or capture video. The sounds play when you call methods like [CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700836) or [StartRecordToStorageFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700863) to notify the user (and people around them) that the camera is active.

I don't know of a way to disable the shutter sound for your app specifically. Is there something you're trying to do that requires a silent capture?

PS: This is a little off-topic, but you've posted a lot more code than is necessary to reproduce the shutter sound, including some code that appears to do rotation. I'd like to refer you to the MSDN page that talks about [detecting screen/device rotation and setting the preview rotation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture#detect-screen-and-device-orientation). Further down you'll also learn the recommended way to [rotate a captured video](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-mediacapture#capture-a-video).

Comment: Thanks for detail info, I tried everyting I can but still having issue, Please check for my edited post I uploaded demo project for you reference, In that project when you capture any image and than try to dispose the resources it's generating shutter sound

Comment: Any help on uploaded sample pls?

Comment: What device are you running this on, and what version of the OS is installed? It works as I describe it on my Windows 10 Lumia 950, the shutter sound only plays when tapping the Capture button, not the Dispose button.

Comment: Strange thing is that I tried on Lumia 640 XL and in that shutter sound is playing during dispose while on Lumia 625 sound is playing on Capture, I just want to disable sound, is there any hack for that?

Comment: Like I said, I don't know of a way to disable the shutter sound for your app specifically. Is there something you're trying to do that requires a silent capture? There might be other things you can try depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: That's right in my app I requires silent capture, I saw many apps on the store that do silent capture but I am out of idea to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to `mediaCaptureElement.Source = null;` then `await capture.StopPreviewAsync();` and then `capture.Dispose();`

Comment: Tried that but still playing shutter sound.

Comment: Try to disable Shutter Sound available in system settings. There is sample to open settings page https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-Launch-settings-6d68c5ba

Comment: Thanks, but there are few apps in the store which don't play shutter sound event if shutter sound is ON, Like #Scan and Comment.